# Concatenate a variable with an Id tag in Pug

Tags: pug

I'm triyng to create dynamic variables using an Id and an incremental number.

```
ul
  - for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    li#id#{i}
```

I expected to get

```
li#id0
li#id1
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pug's id shorthand doesn't work well with dynamic values. Use the standard [attribute syntax](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html) instead.

```
ul
  - for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    li(id= 'id' + i)
```

Or, if you like ES6 template strings:

```
ul
  - for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    li(id=`id${i}`)
```

Both compile to:

```
<ul>
  <li id="id0"></li>
  <li id="id1"></li>
  <li id="id2"></li>
</ul>
```